# Ejb 3 JPA 1.0 Toplink entity autogenerated sequence strategy getId() method return 0 always

Tags: jpa, entity, ejb-3.0, toplink

I have a problem understanding if i have a list of tables with id auto generation sequence strategy or any strategy , how could i get id of entity ? to be precise, i want to query on table entity by id for 
example : select e from employer e where r.ID = :ID 
where could i get this ID to search this employer ?
also at sequence strategy, do i have to set my own sequence generator to get such entity ids or this is not related to my question ?

Iam using glassfish v2.1 toplink jpa 1.0 mysql server.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the title of your question relates to the question itself, but you rarely query by id especially when the id is autogenerated. I would recommend to [define a business key and design an equals and hahscode methods](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode) that ultimately identify your entities.

In terms of defining the sequence generator, you need to [define the primary key of the table as auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html). This strategy will autommatically generate a new id for each new record.

Comment: you say that it's rare to query by id, so what if i have class entity that has many students and i have method getAllStudents(Class c1), so i want to get all students in class c1, how could i query on students in class one c1 without using id ??? thanks in advance

Comment: I think you would query on c1 which would have a list of student associated to it. You can query by id obviously, but in general is not something you know beforehand because is generated by the db.

Comment: is there an alternative way to do such query without knowing id of entity ? if not, i can't get the id of entity using entity.getId()? how can i solve this ?